# Match everything inside a parenthesis

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a regex in PHP that will match all inside a parenthesis, I'm having problem with special characters particullarly the ampersand(&)

If the string inside the parenthesis contains an ampersand it doesn't match.

Here is the sample string

```
_categories=true(test_asda=asd asdasd,asdawqe&hello=asdads)
```

Here is the expected output

```
test_asda=asd asdasd,asdawqe&hello=asdads
```

Here is the regex I'm currently using

```
/\(([^\&)]+)\)/
```

Comment: Added explanation for the regex. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex should be:

```
/\(([^)]+)\)/
```

You're using `[^\&)]+` which means match until you hit an ampersand OR right parentheses that's why it is stopping as soon as it is finding `&`

Comment: I think that `/\((.+)\)/` is enough.

Comment: @ElvedinHamzagic: That will probably work but will be an inefficient regex.

Comment: @PhilipBadilla: The `(` and `)` are special regex characters and thus you need to escape them (place and extra \ in front, which is something you are not doing. `\(([^)]+)\)`.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, your regex definitely worked! thanx!

Comment: @ElvedinHamzagic: The problem with that regex is that it is greedy, meaning that given this: `(foo) bar (fff)` the regex you recommend will match the entire string, instead of `(foo)` and `(fff)`.

Comment: For simple example that user provided it is enough. But of course, it is not redundant to add one more character to test... Maybe you should escape inner bracket, too.

Answer (score 1):

Philip, this simple regex should do what you are trying to do.

```
$result = preg_replace('/_categories=true\(([^)]+)\)/', '\1', $subject);
```

Input: `_categories=true(test_asda=asd asdasd,asdawqe&hello=asdads)`

Output: `test_asda=asd asdasd,asdawqe&hello=asdads`

How does it work? Once we get inside the parentheses, we start capture group 1. What we are capturing is `[^)]+` which means "any number of characters which are not a closing parenthesis", allowing you to consume the string up to the closing parenthesis `)`